# Detecting Orientation and changing classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-orientation

I have built my webpage so that it can adapt to different browsers, devices and sizes. However I have a problem that I want to fix using JavaScript:

I have two classes for my header:      .header and .header2

If the device is less then 679 wide (so most likely mobile) I want it to use .header1 or else I want it to use .header

However if the mobile device is rotated to be landscape I want it go back to using .header

I want this because when I use .header1 the size of the header increases to make is easier to access navigation links. However when the phone is landscape continuing using .header1 means the header takes up too much space on screen.

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--If screen width is below 679 (Mobile Device) changes classes to enlargen header-->
    if (screen.width < screen.height) {
   document.getElementById("HeaderId").className = "Header2";
   document.getElementById("BanImgId").className = "BanImg2";
   document.getElementById("LinksId").className = "Links2";
   document.getElementById("MainId").className = "Main2";
    }
  <!-- Reloads webpage on mobile devices if orientated to return header to default, if rotated back reloads page-->
  $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
   if(window.orientation == 0)
   {
    location.reload();
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("HeaderId").className = "Header";
    document.getElementById("BanImgId").className = "BanImg";
    document.getElementById("LinksId").className = "Links";
    document.getElementById("MainId").className = "Main";
   }
  });
 </script>
```

(I also had to re-size some other things for it to work correctly not just the header)

This was my code, it worked, when testing on my mobile, it did correctly use the header2, being less than 679 and when I rotated the device landscape it did make the header return to using .header However the problem with it is that if I stayed in landscape and reloaded the page it would go back to using .header2 and the header would take up too much space. It has really got my puzzled as I cant quite work out whats going on, I think I am making a mess of something that should be pretty simple.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why not use CSS media queries? you can target screen sizes and orientation as well.

Comment: ^ Dito - I would go with `@media` queries here

Comment: Ok thanks I will have a look at that, it should be faster too? As I dont have to let JS load. Yeah that *should* work, I will have a go.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem perfectly! 
StyleHomeP had a header of 160px 
StyleHomeL had a header of 80px
It updated whenever I rotated the device to switch to the correct orientation. It seems to work by seeing if the width is bigger then the height(landscape) so it also works on desktop really well.